# Getting error when trying to interpolate variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributes, kivy, kivy-language

I can't seem to figure out what 'super' object has no attribute '**getattr**' means. I don't know why I am getting this error.

This is a simple guessing game, I am using Kivy for a GUI

```py
import math
import kivy
kivy.require('1.11.0')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class Layout(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Layout, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.cols = 3
        self.guesses = 10
        self.hasWon = False
        self.pressedStart = False
        self.ids.start.text = 'Start'
        self.ids.gameText.text = 'Press Start when have chosen your number and are ready!'
        self.ids.instructions.text = 'Choose any number between 0 and 20000 and I will guess it in 10 tries!'
        self.max_guess = 20000
        self.min_guess = 0
        self.guess = math.ceil((self.max_guess - self.min_guess) / 2)
        self.ids.guessText.text = f'Guess left: {self.guesses}'


    def higher(self):
        if self.pressedStart == True and self.hasWon == False:
            self.guesses -= 1
            self.min_guess += self.guess
            self.ids.startText.text = f'Is your number {self.guess}?'
        else:
            pass
```

```
    File "guessing_game.py", line 41, in higher
      self.ids.startText.text = f'Is your number {self.guess}?'
    File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 863, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
    AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
```

Comment: I have removed some of the other code as to not over clutter. Let me know if you need it

Comment: I suspect you need to put the code that references `ids` in another method, and call that method via `Clock.schedule_once()` in your `__init__()` method. The `ids` may not yet be available in the `__init__` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problem - AttributeError

```
  self.ids.startText.text = f'Is your number {self.guess}?'
File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 863, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
```

### Root cause

It means that the attribute or variable, `ids.startText` does not exist in either  *`self.ids`* dictionary type property or object, `Layout`.

Comment: Oh wow, I feel so stupid. I was up til 2am trying to figure this out. Thank you.